# My footer is stuck at the top

Tags: html, css, footer

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erjmvvf0/)

My footer is stuck at the top and i want it at the bottom. But I've got everything at the bottom and it doesn't work. I've tried many different things that don't seem to work and it's getting frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/*===========================================
============================FOOTER===========
============================================*/
footer .insta_hover,
footer .fb_hover,
footer .twitter_hover{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    width: 42px;
    color: #000;
    font: 1.6em/1.3 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    top: -10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

footer .fbhover{
    margin-top: 27px;
}


footer .icon_container{
    position: absolute;
    right: 260px;
    z-index: 500;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    width:auto;

}


.copywrite{
    color: #999;
    /*font: 10px/36px 'brandon-grotesque';*/

    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;  
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;      
}
.Find{
        color: #999;
    /*font: 10px/36px 'brandon-grotesque';*/

    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;  
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;    
    left:1000px
}

/* 
Footer-Styles 
*/  

footer {
    clear: both;    
    font-size:0.8em;  
    background:#333;
    min-height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom:0;

}  
/* 
Sticky Footer 
*/

footer a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;

}
footer li{
    display:inline;

}

footer .container {
    padding-top:20px;
}

p{
    left:80px;
    top:200px;
}





 <footer>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="copywrite">
      © 2015 www.imadgames.com All Rights Reserved.   </p>  

    <div class="icon_container">
      <ul class="hover_block">
        <li>
            <a href = 'https://twitter.com/' class="twitter_hover"><img src="img/twitter_icon.png" alt="Imad Games @ twitter" style="bottom: 0px;"></a>
            <a href = 'https://www.facebook.com' class="fb_hover"><img src="img/Facebook_icon.png" alt="Imad Games @ facebook" style="bottom: 0px;"></a>   
            <a href = 'https://www.instagram.com/_imadinho_/' class="insta_hover"><img src="img/insta_icon.png" alt="Imad Games @ instagram" style="bottom: 0px;"></a>        

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you make a demo in JSfiddle.net to show the issue. At the moment we can't really telll what the issue is. Perhaps searching for "Sticky Footer".

Comment: if you just want your footer to be at the bottom, use position: absolute; in your footer element in css, so, footer { position:absolute; }

Comment: when i put it to absolute it goes to the middle in one of my big pages.

Comment: unless you have something going outside the footer {}, whatever you set your footer to be, height and width wise, it'll stay that way. So if its in the middle of one of your pages its because you have something within the footer pushing it up, could be an image, could be margins or padding

Comment: what can be pushing it up?

Comment: since i cant see your code i dont know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
footer .insta_hover,
footer .fb_hover,
footer .twitter_hover{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    width: 42px;
    color: #000;
    font: 1.6em/1.3 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    top: -10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

footer .fbhover{
    margin-top: 27px;
}


footer .icon_container{
    position: absolute;
    right: 260px;
    z-index: 500;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    width:auto;

}


.copywrite{
    color: #999;
    /*font: 10px/36px 'brandon-grotesque';*/

    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;  
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;      
}
.Find{
        color: #999;
    /*font: 10px/36px 'brandon-grotesque';*/

    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;  
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;    
    left:1000px
}

/* 
Footer-Styles 
*/  

footer {
    clear: both;    
    font-size:0.8em;  
    background:#333;
    min-height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom:0;

}  
/* 
Sticky Footer 
*/

footer a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;

}
footer li{
    display:inline;

}

footer .container {
    padding-top:20px;
}

p{
    left:80px;
    top:200px;
}
```

```html
 <footer>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="copywrite">
      © 2015 www.imadgames.com All Rights Reserved.   </p>  

    <div class="icon_container">
      <ul class="hover_block">
        <li>
            <a href = 'https://twitter.com/' class="twitter_hover"><img src="http://www.heart.org/idc/groups/heart-public/@wcm/@global/documents/image/ucm_300157.png" alt="Imad Games @ twitter" style="bottom: 0px;"></a>
            <a href = 'https://www.facebook.com' class="fb_hover"><img src="http://www.royalgoldphones.com/images/fb.png" alt="Imad Games @ facebook" style="bottom: 0px;"></a>   
            <a href = 'https://www.instagram.com/_imadinho_/' class="insta_hover"><img src="https://annaconnerandco.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/instagram-icon-32px.png" alt="Imad Games @ instagram" style="bottom: 0px;"></a>        

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

--just you need to change     **position: relative;** to  **position: absolute;** in footer class

Thank you

Comment: when i do that this happens https://www.dropbox.com/s/mz8xsw7yhqjkxil/Picture1.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Do this and remove the position from other elements inside your footer

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS Property

```
footer {
  position: absolute; 
}
```

instead of

```
footer {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@charset "utf-8";
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -330px;
    position: relative;
}
/*=====================
 ====Fonts-Styles ====
 ====================*/

@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat-Bold";
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Bold.otf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat-Reg";
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.otf');
}
/*=====================
 ====Background-Styles ====
 ====================*/

#search {
    width: 400px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 37%;
    top: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffcd00;
}
h2.headline {
    font: 2.3em 'Montserrat-Bold', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0.75em;
    margin-top: 130px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Reg', sans-serif;
    min-width: 950px;
    background-image: url("img/background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
#logo {
    background-image: url(img/Logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 1630px;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav {
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 4px;
    top: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    width: 505px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 1950px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Bold', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
    background-color: #303030;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.nav ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 7px;
}
.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 11px 11px 11px 11px;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color: #ffcd00;
}
/*========TABLES & FORMS=======*/

table,
td,
th {
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #221f20;
    color: #ffffff
}
#tables {
    top: 190px;
    right: 35%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ffcd00;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#resform {
    width: 400px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 7;
    left: 39%;
    top: 220px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffcd00;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/*===========================================
============================FOOTER===========
============================================*/

footer {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background: #333;
    min-height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
footer .icon_container {
    position: absolute;
    right: 260px;
    z-index: 500;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}
.copywrite {
    color: #999;
    /*font: 10px/36px 'brandon-grotesque';*/

    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    top: 8px;
}
.Find {
    color: #999;
    /*font: 10px/36px 'brandon-grotesque';*/

    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    top: 8px;
    left: 1000px
}
/* 
Footer-Styles 
*/

footer {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background: #333;
    min-height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
/* 
Sticky Footer 
*/

footer a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
footer li {
    display: inline;
}
footer .container {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
p {
    left: 80px;
    top: 200px;
}
```